# Technical term for describing an algorithm that "exposes trade-off between locally and globally optimal decisions"

Tags: algorithm, optimization, naming, tradeoff

What is the technical term for describing an algorithm that "exposes trade-off between locally and globally optimal decisions"?

It's gonna be part of a name, so I would appreciate replacing the above-mentioned description with a shorter yet appropriate term.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a heuristic to me.

Comment: "exposes trade-off between locally and globally optimal decisions" - what does it mean?  I know what are locally and globally optimal solutions of optimization problem.  What is "trade-off" between them, and how to "expose" it?

Comment: Actually it is a heuristic. I want to emphasize on its ability for making local sacrifices for global benefits, based on some newly defined attributes.
It is an algorithm for solving a scheduling problem where local optimization would be trying to minimize the execution time of the current job, while global optimization would be trying to develop some lookahead features in order to minimize the overal execution time of all jobs.

Comment: Looks like that the technical term would be a "relaxation" of the subproblem in benefit of the main problem. Look at the "lagrangian relaxation" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_relaxation)

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I truly appreciate your suggestion. "Relaxation" sounds fine to me.